# I installed some other phones flash file into my phone and my phone is not booting neither detected by pc, help me

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

Just for experiment I installed some other phones flash file into my phone using sp flash tool, flashing that file succeeded, SP flash tool successfully flashed that file into my device...

But when I started to turn on the phone, phone is not turning on neither even screen starts up.. I do not know what happened to my phone..

My phone model is Rivo RX45 and it is made by Rivo company.. My phone processor is mediatek mt6572. Flash file that I installed was from the following page: http://fixfirmwares.com/gowin-f7-firmware-mt6572/

Now when I tried to format my device from sp flash tool, device is not detected by the pc. Help me please

Comment: you probably flashed wrong preloader now your device is hard bricked. btw the linked ROM does not even match your device specifications

Comment: what is solution sir?

Comment: preloader is required. check if preloader is visible in device manager 1st second when connected, like this. if you remove battery it should loop every 5 seconds. if you can't hear or see it, there is no hope https://youtu.be/O2XWTAYmNUo

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/d1s7x6sc1x2w2qk/Rivo_RX45_MIRA.zip